# How to launch the Settings app in a Windows Store app running on a desktop/notebook

Tags: windows-store-apps

I know that a store app can't launch another app, but is there a way to offer the user a button which opens the System Network Settings?

edit:
I try to ask with more details:
Under win 10 (Desktop and phone) and under Windows 8.1 on a phone I can use the uris "ms-settings-wifi:" and "ms-settings-wifi://" to Launch the wifi-settings.

I didn't find an uri to launch the settings in store app running on a desktop/notebook.

Greetings from Germany
Ralf

Comment: Store apps *can* launch other apps (e..g [launch the Bing Maps app via the bingmaps: URI protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj635237.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396))

Comment: hi @Juhana and thanks for your reply. I knew this way and under https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj662937(v=vs.105).aspx you can find the Windows Phone 8 URI and under https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn741261.aspx you can find the Windows 10 (great!) and Windows phone 8.1 URI. Unfortunally I didn't find a list for Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this is a very special problem and therefore only someone with very deep windows knowledge can help.
So I asked this question in an MSDN-Forum and Barry Wang gave me the unwanted answer:
It won't be possible on Windows 8.1.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/81fa61ae-a0ac-4236-a96f-e8dcebd18e10/how-to-launch-the-settings-app-in-a-windows-store-app-running-on-a-desktopnotebook?forum=wpdevelop

Best regards
Ralf